# Ao rodar um servico: acontece o seguiente erro. Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value

Tags: c#, json, web-service

FrameWork 4.0
**Bloco de código que gera o erro**

```
var token = Configuracao.Config.TokenAgrometrika;

if (Configuracao.Config.ValidateTokenAgrometrika > DateTime.Now) return token;

   var autenticacao = new Autenticacao()
   {
        Chave = Configuracao.Config.ChaveAgrometrika,
        ID = Configuracao.Config.IdAgrometrika
   };
Tools.Log(string.Format("Pegando token de autorização. Chave: {0} ID: {1}", autenticacao.Chave, autenticacao.ID));

var _cliente = new HttpClient(Handler, true);                   
var url = Configuracao.Config.Url.EndsWith("/") ? Configuracao.Config.Url : Configuracao.Config.Url + "/";

if (!Configuracao.Config.Url.EndsWith("api/") && !Configuracao.Config.Url.EndsWith("APIv2/"))
{
    url = Configuracao.Config.Url + "api/";                       
}                    
_cliente.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
_cliente.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
_cliente.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

*{Error happens here}*

var response = _cliente.PostAsJsonAsync("Autenticacao", autenticacao).Result;
```

Erro depois do response.

> Erro: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
>      em Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
>      em Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
>      em Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
>      em Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
>      em Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
>      em Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)

Comment: Confere qual é o retorno do webservice, provavelmente não é um JSON.

Comment: Estamos no Stack Overflow em Português e, como o próprio nome sugere, o idioma a ser utilizado deve ser o português. Por favor, edite novamente sua pergunta e traduza-a. Antes disso, leia como [formatar sua pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) corretamente.

Comment: O Problema que ele funciona quando estou debugando, só acontece o erro quando gero o exe e instalo o executavel